# Setting up an exit node on VPS along with a VPN. Impact to anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, exit-relays, vpn, vps

If I run a VPS (using Orange VPS provider out of Iceland, purchased with monero-filtered bitcoin) as a TOR exit node, and that VPS (running Streisand) is also the VPS I use for a privately controlled VPN, does that inject the VPN traffic with the outgoing TOR traffic via shared IP?

If I engage the VPN tunnel to my VPS after establishing my own TOR circuit, does that successfully keep the VPS provider from seeing the originating IP as long as the TOR circuit remains intact and no direct log-in happens from that IP without going through TOR?

Comment: If you mean *"Will my VPN traffic look like Exit traffic?"* the answer is *"No"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the question is multi-part, and the final answer will depend on how you're making the combo in your particular case, here you go:

- Running VPN and Tor node on the same VPS has nothing to do with security or privacy degrading: it's absolutely safe **by itself**
- Remember, that VPN is a **strict** *and* **direct** service, i.e. if something is connecting to a VPN server - so it's a 100% clear that it's a VPN client and nothing else. So :

  1. if you'll connect to the VPN via clearnet Internet - yes, your IP and VPS IP are corellated.
  2. if your VPN is listening to darknet(dot-onion) address only - it's not binding your IP to VPS IP due to the nature of the Tor hidden services

Comment: Thanks. It would be option 2. I would only VPN into the VPS through TOR. I would do all the initial VPS set-up through TOR as well, so there should be no direct link back to my own originating IP. I could route traffic through (my now relatively trusted) exit node by editing the torrc file, yes?

Comment: option 2 has no impacts, you're safe

Comment: Thanks again. Does the automatic TOR routing change (and corresponding exit node switch) adversely impact the VPN functionality? Would there be an improvement in VPN bandwidth and stability of connection by pinning the exit node to the VPS exit node? Could I fix the VPN TOR exit node to exclusively be the TOR exit node I have set up on the VPS by editing the torrc file? Alternatively, I could ditch the VPN at that point except for VPS monitoring, and route all other traffic through TOR the normal way (i.e. not over VPN), except with my exit node fixed to the VPS in the torrc file.

Comment: add your VPN port to (LongLivedPorts)[https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#LongLivedPorts] on your *client* tor